# javascript timer returns NaN while giving condition

Tags: javascript

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var hoursleft = 0;
    var minutesleft = 0; // you can change these values to any value greater than 0
    var secondsleft = 0;
    var millisecondsleft = 0;
    var finishedtext = "Your Time is Up Question Switch to Others!"; // text that appears when the countdown reaches 0
    end = new Date();

    //end.setHours(end.getHours()+hoursleft);
    end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() + minutesleft);
    end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds() + secondsleft);
    end.setMilliseconds(end.getMilliseconds() + millisecondsleft);

    function cd() {

        now = new Date();
        diff = end - now;
        diff = new Date(diff);
        var msec = diff.getMilliseconds();
        var sec = diff.getSeconds() ;
        var min = diff.getMinutes();
        //var hr = diff.getHours() - 1;

        if (min < 10) {
            min = "0" + min;
        }
        if (sec < 10) {
            sec = "0" + sec;
        }
        if (msec < 10) {
            msec = "00" + msec;
        } else if (msec < 100) {
            msec = "0" + msec;
        }
        if (sec== 0) {
            //clearTimeout(timerID);
            //document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML = finishedtext;
            //alert("Your time is Up Switch to Others");
            timerID = setTimeout("cdd()", 100);

            //$("#cdtime").slideUp( 300 ).delay( 8000 ).fadeIn( 400 );  
        } else {
            document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML = +sec;
            timerID = setTimeout("cd()", 100);
        } // you can leave out the + ":" + msec if you want...
        // If you do so, you should also change setTimeout to setTimeout("cd()",1000)
    }


    function cdd() {
        now = new Date();
        diff = end - now;
        diff = new Date(diff);
        var msec = diff.getMilliseconds();
        var sec = diff.getSeconds() -29;
        var min = diff.getMinutes();
        //var hr = diff.getHours() - 1;
        if (min < 10) {
            min = "0" + min;
        }
        if (sec < 10) {
            sec = "0" + sec;
        }
        if (msec < 10) {
            msec = "00" + msec;
        } else if (msec < 100) {
            msec = "0" + msec;
        }
        if (sec == 0) {
            clearTimeout(timerID);
            confirm("Time is over");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML = +sec;
        } 
        timerID = setTimeout("cdd()", 100); 
    }

    window.onload = cd;
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="cdtime"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi I need to make timer for first 60 seconds after 60seconds another 30seconds want run in the web page. In that I gave a condition if(sec==0) means another 30 seconds want to run but what is the problem means it shows NaN for 0 which I gave the condition. so please help me how to do without NaN.So the timer want to run first 60seconds and after 30 seconds without showing NaN(not a number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first parameter of `setTimeout` function is a function or the name of the function (not the call). So you should replace all this kind of lines:

   `timerID = setTimeout("cd()", 100);` by this: `timerID = setTimeout(cd, 100);`

   For more details about `setTimeout` function, please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).
2. For some reason, in your `cdd` function the following line:

   `var sec = diff.getSeconds() - 29;`

   returns a negative value and after this line:

   `sec = "0" + sec;`

   the value of `sec` is become equal to `0-*the number*` (for example, `"0-10"`), which is not a number as you have said.

   The possible solution is to use `Math.abs()` to have an absolute value of the `sec` variable. Just like this:

   `var sec = Math.abs(diff.getSeconds() - 29);`

Comment: Quite true, but not really related to the problem faced or the question asked.